# Modules - CP Template not found

Tags: modules

I've used this tool to generate a module: https://pluginfactory.io/

So in my constructor, I have

```
 Event::on(View::class, View::EVENT_REGISTER_CP_TEMPLATE_ROOTS, function (RegisterTemplateRootsEvent $e) {
            if (is_dir($baseDir = $this->getBasePath().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'templates')) {
                $e->roots[$this->id] = $baseDir;
            }
        });
```

In my init() function I have this

```
 Event::on(
            Cp::class,
            Cp::EVENT_REGISTER_CP_NAV_ITEMS,
            function(RegisterCpNavItemsEvent $event) {
                $event->navItems[] = [
                    'url' => 'leads',
                    'label' => 'Leads Management'
                ];
            }
        );
```

When I click the link on the control panel, I will get a Template Not Found error.

My template folder is located at `modules/leadsmodule/src/templates`

Inside templates I have a file called `leads.twig`.

I did die() on the `$baseDir` that it's being set to in the constructor and got the path: `modules\leadsmodule\src\templates`

I need my control panel item to load a specific template.

What am I doing wrong?

---

Edit: the control panel URI for my item looks like `/admin/leads`

Here is my config/app.php

```
'*' => [
        'modules'   => [
            'leads-module' => [
                'class' => \modules\leadsmodule\LeadsModule::class,
            ],
        ],
        'bootstrap' => ['leads-module'],
    ],
```

I've tried every combination to load the template I can think of.

In side my modules/leadmodule/src/templates I've placed the following

```
admin/leads-module/leads.twig

admin/leadsmodule/leads.twig

/admin/leads.twig

/leads-module/admin/leads.twig

/leads-module/leads.twig

/leadsmodule/admin/leads.twig

/leadsmodule/leads.twig

/leads.twig
```

Still get a 404 template not found: leads when accesses /admin/leads from the control panel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It must be `/admin/module-id/leads`. So in your case maybe `/admin/leadsmodule/leads` or `/admin/leads-module/leads` depending on your ID if you want to access it directly via template route.

Otherwhise you need to create custom URL rules

Comment: In config/app i'm using 'leads-module'. I've tried putting inside the module folder /admin/leads-module/leads and still get Template not found: leads. I've also put it in the regular templates folder in root and still get the same error. Can you show me a working example using the pluginfactory.io link?

Comment: i've edited my question showing combos of template paths i've used

Comment: Not really sure what I should show. Your basic code is correct, you just should not append `.twig` to the url. just typing `admin/leads-module/leads`should show you the correct template if it's not empty

Comment: Oh I misunderstood, I thought those were template paths rather than urls. I got it to work by accessing the URI `/admin/leads-module/leads` which corresponds to the template path `/src/templates/leads.twig`.